# Why is Goku's origin different between the Dragonball and the Galactic Patrolman series?

Tags: dragon-ball

Why is Son Goku 3 (when he lands on earth)in [Galactic Patrolman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaco_the_Galactic_Patrolman) but only 2 (when he lands on earth) in the [Dragon Ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Ball) anime and manga?

Comment: I had to guess a bit... I was thinking you meant age, but he's 11 at the beginning of Dragonball. Are you talking about the number of Dragon Balls found, 2 in the first volume of *Jaco the Galactic Patrolman* and 1 at the beginning of *Dragon Ball*?

Comment: Yes like he was sent/found

Comment: Only when he was he sent/found on earth

Comment: I'm still not following what you're saying... are you asking about his age or the number of Dragon Balls? Would it be easier if we discussed this in Chat?

Comment: @SeanDuggan i believe that he means the age of goku when he landed on earth, hes about 2 in dragon ball, and they must specifically say he lands when hes 3 in galactic patrolman. Goku was sent from the planet vegeta as a baby/small child.

Comment: honestly this age difference could either be due to translation errors, OR akira forgetting exactly how old goku was, 30 years ago when he started dragon ball.

Comment: Or, as per my answer, that *Jaco* has a framing device of being recounted by someone else after the fact. But I had thought he was older when he landed. :) I learn something.

Comment: Despite definitely being a sci-fi/fantasy series, wouldn't a question like this be better placed in the Anime SE?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer (and the only one I can render, not entirely understanding your question) is that the *Jaco* stories are being narrated by Omori in retrospect, so details may vary from what "actually" happened, assuming that they're not simply separate continuities or Akira made a mistake.

Comment: Yes when he was found/sent